# HTML video element not working on i-pad devices

Tags: html, html5-video

I've got an issue that has been addressed a number of times before and I've been trying to sort it myself but I haven't been able to, so far. Here's the piece of HTML:

```
<video id="video1"  class="w-100 h-100" autoplay="autoplay" playsinline loop
            muted >
            <source src="./src/media/new-user.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
            <source src="./src/media/new-user.webm" type="video/webm"/>
            <source src="./src/media/new-user.mov" type="video/mov"/>
            </video>
```

I've tried everything that's been suggested so far so any other ideas would be helpful. My video element is running on autoplay either on my Android phone or on a Mac(any browser), but it's not visible on any browser I tried on i-pad devices. I thought of adding a couple of alternative sources on my last attempt but that didn't solve the problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: So is the video not playing at all, or just not autoplaying?

Comment: Not playing at all.

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<source>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-source-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Answer (score 0):

Just for future reference in case someone else is stuck I figured it out myself. Basically according to Apple .mp4 videos have to meet some certain specifications, and mine were slightly larger in size. Extra source files .webm and .mov not necessary.
[https://confluence.atlassian.com/confkb/unable-to-play-embedded-mp4-videos-on-ipad-or-iphone-in-confluence-305037325.html][1]